# Never-ending ajax request, good idea / bad idea?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

For the backend of my site, visible only to a few people, I have a system whereby I communicate with a php via ajax like so:

```
function ajax(url, opts) {
    var progress = false, all_responses = [], previousResponseLength = "";
    var ajaxOptions = {
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        xhrFields: {
            onprogress: function(e) {
                if (!e.target.responseText.endsWith("\n")) return;
                var response = e.target.responseText.substring(previousResponseLength).trim();
                previousResponseLength = e.target.responseText.length;
                var responses = response.split(/[\r\n]+/g);
                var last_response;
                for (var k in responses) {
                    if (responses[k] === "---START PROGRESS---") {
                        progress = true;
                        if (opts.onProgressInit) opts.onProgressInit();
                    } else if (responses[k] === "---END PROGRESS---") progress = false;
                    else all_responses.push(last_response = responses[k]);
                }
                if (progress && last_response !== undefined) opts.onProgress(JSON.parse(all_responses[all_responses.length-1]));
            }
        },
        dataFilter: function(data){
            return all_responses[all_responses.length-1];
        }
    }

    $.extend(ajaxOptions, {
        onProgress: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

And an example of a never-ending php script (until the user closes the connection):

```
const AJAX_START_PROGRESS = "---START PROGRESS---";
const AJAX_END_PROGRESS = "---END PROGRESS---";

session_write_close(); //fixes problem of stalling entire php environment while script runs
set_time_limit(0); //allows to the script to run indefinitely
output(AJAX_START_PROGRESS);
while(true) {
    output(json_encode(["asdasd" => "asasdas"]));
    sleep(1);
}

function output($msg) {
    echo preg_replace("`[\r\n]+`", "", $msg).PHP_EOL;
    ob_flush(); flush();
}
```

This allows me through 1 ajax request to 'poll' (am I using that term correctly?)
So if I want to execute a very long php script I can now check its progress, and the last response is delivered via jqhxr.done(callback).

Or, as in the example php script, I can open a connection and leave it open. Using sleep(1); It issues an update to the $.ajax object every 1 second.
Every response has to be json encoded, and if the response is 1 very long json that comes over multiple 'onprogress' calls, it waits until the end of the message (if responseText.endsWith("\n")) we're ready!)

My remote shared server didn't allow websockets so I made this. If the user closes the connection, so does the php script.
It's only got to work for a few admins with special privileges, and I don't need to worry about old browsers.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this script? Through googling I haven't found anybody else with this kind of method, so I expect something is wrong with it.
Extensive testing tells me it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invented `long polling request`, actually it's wide used as fallback to `websockets`, so nothing wrong with it.
About your code it's hard to say without testing, but when using such methods as long-polling, you need to double check memory leaks on browser side and on server side.